# Entity Framework loses track of navigation properties after "over apply"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a model like *Person*, which can live on *Street*, and *Street* is in the *City*, and *City* in it's turn is in the *Country*. Also there is some *ActivityRecords* for some *Persons*.

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public int country_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
public class Street
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("City")]
    public int city_id { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    ForeignKey("Street")]
    public int? street_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Street Street { get; set; }

    //no connection to ActivityRecord[]
}

public class ActivityRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int? person_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I need to list a portion of persons info, including their addresses up to the country plus one of the activities if there's any (otherwise null). I have deliberately dropped all of the details and columns to simplify the example.

So, I have come to this in my code:

```
context.Persons.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(p => p.id).Skip(0).Take(10).GroupJoin(
    context.ActivityRecords,
    p => p.id,
    ar => ar.person_id,
    (p, ar) => new { p = p, ar = ar.FirstOrDefault() } //join 1 or 0 entries
).Select(result => new
{
    id = result.t.id,
    street = result.t.Street.name,
    city = result.t.Street.City.name,
    country = result.t.Street.City.Country.name
}).ToArray();
```

When I check EF-generated query, I see left-outer-joins on same tables multiple times (streets, cities):

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent3].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent5].[name] AS [name1], 
    [Extent8].[name] AS [name2]
    FROM         (SELECT TOP (10) [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[street_id] AS [street_id]
        FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[street_id] AS [street_id], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[id] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[id] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent2].[id] AS [id]
        FROM [dbo].[ActivityRecords] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Limit1].[id] = [Extent2].[person_id] ) AS [Limit2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Streets] AS [Extent3]
            ON [Limit1].[street_id] = [Extent3].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Streets] AS [Extent4]  /* <-- Seriously? */
            ON [Limit1].[street_id] = [Extent4].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cities] AS [Extent5]
            ON [Extent4].[city_id] = [Extent5].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Streets] AS [Extent6] /* <-- Come on! */
            ON [Limit1].[street_id] = [Extent6].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cities] AS [Extent7] /* <-- Hey! */
            ON [Extent6].[city_id] = [Extent7].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Countries] AS [Extent8]
            ON [Extent7].[country_id] = [Extent8].[id]
```

When I just remove the single row connection in group join

> ...(p, ar) => new { p = p, ar = ar } ...

it works fine and joins each table once.

I tried to include tables before *join*, but with no success. The only thing that work is to make selection of all *person-streets-cities* before *join*, but the problem is that it loads all of that records **before** cutting TOP 10, and in reality I have there lots of heavy calculated columns (this query, when problem is still visible, is much simpler if you remove *Skip()* and *Take()*, but leave *GroupJoin()* with *FirstOrDefault()*).

So, my question is: how to inform EF not to include same tables multiple times, is there a workaround? Why it start loosing track of navigation properties chain after single row connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was really a bug in EF query compilation, so upgrading from **EF 6.1.1** to **EF 6.1.2** fixed the problem.